# Efficient concatenation of large number of arrays in Julia

Tags: arrays, performance, julia, concatenation

I am using Julia to build a large N x N matrix. It basically consists of repeating the same array:

```
 L = [1 0; 1 0; 0 0; 0 0]
```

I basically want this to be repeated N times, vertically and horizontally, for an 2N x 4N array for some general L. The problem is that, when I use hcat, it's very inconvenient, as I believe that I have to put L in N number of times:

```
cat(dims=2,L,L,L,L,L,L,L,...)
```

I also didn't have much luck with `hvcat`. What is the easiest (and most efficient) way to build this large array from L? I would like something as fast as possible, as this a small portion of a much larger code. I expect N to be of the order of 100 or larger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `repeat` function:

```
L = [1 0; 1 0; 0 0; 0 0];
N = 3;
repeat(L; outer=(N, N));
```

Output

```
julia> repeat(L; outer=(N, N))
12×6 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  0  1  0  1  0
 1  0  1  0  1  0
 0  0  0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0  0  0
 1  0  1  0  1  0
 1  0  1  0  1  0
 0  0  0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0  0  0
 1  0  1  0  1  0
 1  0  1  0  1  0
 0  0  0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0  0  0
```

I assume that you meant that you want a 4N-by-2N matrix, not 2N-by-4N. There is also an `inner` keyword you can use, which repeats each value instead of the whole input array.